# Show PDF file in C# Windows application with annotation facility

Tags: c#, pdf

I am using `Acrobat Reader 10.1.0` which provide annotation facility. And I want to show `PDF` file in my C# application so that I can use this annotation facility.

For this I approaches two solutions:

1. Use Web Browser control (System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser), and it shows `PDF` file successfully in my C# application.
2. Acrobat `PDF` Reader COM component, and it also shows `PDF` file successfully in my C# application.

But the problem on both the solution is, I can't use annotation facility. As annotation is disabled when `PDF` opened in C#.NET application.

**NOTE:** Annotation facility is like, add your comments in `PDF` file, highlight some text in `PDF` file.

Regards

Pushkar

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a third-party component or library.

One example that does exactly what you ask is Atalasoft DotImage (www.atalasoft.com), but it is not free.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible ways, that I know if, to get around this:

1) Dont use Acrobat and provide your own interface (might be a good idea if web based)

2) Look for an off-the-shelf solution

3) Open Acrobat/Reader from your own application (ie not within the same interface/form) and try to detect changes to the file.